# VB6 ADO connection issue, Jet aborts even though no connection is active

Tags: ms-access, vb6, database-connection, legacy

I'm maintaining a legacy VB6 application that uses Access as DB. With a certain client I'm getting weird errors when manipulating data. I get this error:

```
2012-08-23 17:04:49 The Microsoft Jet database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.
```

But I'm sure I'm the only one running the program so I'm suspecting a connection that stays open somewhere in the program because of an error. The application is very, very ugly... Is there a way for me to see how many connections are active? What do I do to make sure there's only one connection active? Just be sure to close all connections that have been open?

Any other ideas or tips you could pass my way? Thanks

Comment: Did you see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182867? Sometimes this can be due to a recordset and form updating the same data.

Comment: To help tracking down your problem: Search your code for all recordsets that open a table in write mode. Also if you know on which table the problem occurs, you can specifically look your code for SQL changing that table.

Comment: You probably have multiple connections open at the same time.  This is really a program bug, yet getting around it can often mean you'll need to move to a DataEnvironmnt if you are using any data bound controls.  Cleaning up a creaky old program can be a lot of work, a lot of people who use VB6 have limited comprehension and discipline.

Comment: @BobRiemersma: And a lot of people make a lot of unfounded assumptions.